# Joining time series by common date in Python (dataframe & series/list question)

Tags: python, pandas, list, join, series

Noob here. PLEASE FORGIVE ABYSMAL FORMATTING as I am still learning. I am trying to create a time series (a dataframe, I think?) that consists of three columns. One is a date column, the next is an inventory column, and the last is a price column.

I have pulled two separate series (date & inventory; date & price) and I want to meld the two series so that I can see three columns instead of two sets of two. This is my code.

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
from urllib.request import urlopen

class EIAgov(object):
    def __init__(self, token, series):
        '''
        Purpose:
        Initialise the EIAgov class by requesting:
        - EIA token
        - id code(s) of the series to be downloaded

        Parameters:
        - token: string
        - series: string or list of strings
        '''
        self.token = token
        self.series = series


    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.series)


    def Raw(self, ser):
        # Construct url
        url = 'http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=' + self.token + '&series_id=' + ser.upper()

        try:
            # URL request, URL opener, read content
            response = urlopen(url);
            raw_byte = response.read()
            raw_string = str(raw_byte, 'utf-8-sig')
            jso = json.loads(raw_string)
            return jso

        except HTTPError as e:
            print('HTTP error type.')
            print('Error code: ', e.code)

        except URLError as e:
            print('URL type error.')
            print('Reason: ', e.reason)

    def GetData(self):
        # Deal with the date series                       
        date_ = self.Raw(self.series[0])        
        date_series = date_['series'][0]['data']
        endi = len(date_series) # or len(date_['series'][0]['data'])
        date = []
        for i in range (endi):
            date.append(date_series[i][0])

        # Create dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=date)
        df.columns = ['Date']

        # Deal with data
        lenj = len(self.series)
        for j in range (lenj):
            data_ = self.Raw(self.series[j])
            data_series = data_['series'][0]['data']
            data = []
            endk = len(date_series)         
            for k in range (endk):
                data.append(data_series[k][1])
            df[self.series[j]] = data

        return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tok = 'mytoken'

    # Natural Gas - Weekly Storage
    #     
    ngstor = ['NG.NW2_EPG0_SWO_R48_BCF.W']  # w/ several series at a time ['ELEC.REV.AL-ALL.M', 'ELEC.REV.AK-ALL.M', 'ELEC.REV.CA-ALL.M']
    stordata = EIAgov(tok, ngstor)
    print(stordata.GetData())

    # Natural Gas - Weekly Prices
    #     
    ngpx = ['NG.RNGC1.W']  # w/ several series at a time ['ELEC.REV.AL-ALL.M', 'ELEC.REV.AK-ALL.M', 'ELEC.REV.CA-ALL.M']
    pxdata = EIAgov(tok, ngpx)
    print(pxdata.GetData())
```

Note that 'mytoken' needs to be replaced by an eia.gov API key. I can get this to successfully create an output of two lists...but then to get the lists merged I tried to add this at the end:

```
joined_frame = pd.concat([ngstor, ngpx], axis = 1, sort=False)

print(joined_frame.GetData())
```

But I get an error

```
 ("TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid")
```

because apparently I don't know the difference between a list and a series.

How do I merge these lists by date column? Thanks very much for any help. (Also feel free to advise why I am terrible at formatting code correctly in this post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate them as DataFrames in the rest of your code, you can transform `ngstor` and `ngpx` into DataFrames as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
# I create two lists that look like yours
ngstor = [[1,2], ["2020-04-03", "2020-05-07"]]
ngpx = [[3,4] , ["2020-04-03", "2020-05-07"]]
# I transform them to DataFrames
ngstor = pd.DataFrame({"value1": ngstor[0],
                       "date_col": ngstor[1]})
ngpx = pd.DataFrame({"value2": ngpx[0],
                       "date_col": ngpx[1]})
```

Then you can either use `pandas.merge` or `pandas.concat` :

```
# merge option
joined_framed = pd.merge(ngstor, ngpx, on="date_col",
                          how="outer")
```

```
# concat option
ngstor = ngstor.set_index("date_col")
ngpx = ngpx.set_index("date_col")
joined_framed = pd.concat([ngstor, ngpx], axis=1,
                          join="outer").reset_index()
```

The result will be:

```
    date_col  value1  value2
0  2020-04-03       1       3
1  2020-05-07       2       4
```

Comment: Thank you, Raphaele! You are my new best friend. I adapted the concat option and it worked for me. Much appreciated!! Sorry I can't upvote because I am new so my votes don't count.